# Question asked but answer no longer valid

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, obsolete-answers

What do you do if the answer to a question you have asked is no longer valid due to changes made by the website? For example [this one about YouTube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39670/youtube-shows-real-name-when-i-post).

Answer (score 5):

Downvote it and leave a comment that it's no longer valid. You should post a new answer with updated instructions

Comment: Unless, I would say, when the question was asked in context of a certain version of the application that still exists in parallel.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek yeah, that's fair

Comment: I really don't think it's nice to the answerer to downvote an answer because the website / application has changed since then.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the downvote will serve as an indicator to update the answer. Once updated the downvote can be revoked.

Comment: @Sathya How about just adding a warning at the beginning of the answer?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt what's the point? Answers on [se] should strive for accuracy. An answer with a warning doesn't do any good, might as well delete it

Comment: @Sathya I am not sure that it's the best way to keep contributors: maybe just deleting / greying out their answers but keeping their reputation points?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt you get to keep rep on deleted posts provided they have [been around for 60 days, and have a score of 3](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

Comment: @Sathya Interesting, thanks, I didn't know.